# How to define on-click events for nodes using flowchart.js

Tags: javascript, raphael, flowchart

Does flowchart.js supports on-click event handlers? 
Can any one help me to define event handlers for nodes using flowchart.js

Comment: As the requirement was to move the scrollbar to a particular position on clicking a node, I have resolved this issue by specifying anchor URL for the node.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a javascript function to node clicks. Take the following definition:

```
op1=>operation: My Operation:>javascript:dostuff(5)
```

When clicked, this will call the function `dostuff` with the parameter 5.

I don't think this behavior is documented, but it mirrors that of anchors in HTML, where the same thing is possible:

```
<a href="javascript:dostuff(5)">Do Stuff</a>
```